# how to chose user media input in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm now writing software to broadcast live stream from user via html5 and js, and i get a trouble. I have 2 webcams and 3 audio inputs on the server, how can I chose which media device I will get when will call getUserMedia(..)?
Now i use chrome, but it's will be better, if solution will work on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Given the [current draft](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#idl-def-MediaStreamConstraints) (13. August) of the WebRTC-API, **it is not possible to specify a specific recording device**. This choice has to be made by the user himself:

> User agents are encouraged to default to using the user's primary or
>   system default camera and/or microphone (when possible) to generate
>   the media stream. User agents may allow users to use any media source,
>   including pre-recorded media files.

The getUserMedia()-method only allows to specify whether the media source should be a video or audio source via [MediaStreamConstraints](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#idl-def-MediaStreamConstraints):

```
interface NavigatorUserMedia {
    void getUserMedia (MediaStreamConstraints? constraints, NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback successCallback, optional NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback? errorCallback);
};

dictionary MediaStreamConstraints {
    (boolean or MediaTrackConstraints) video = false;;
    (boolean or MediaTrackConstraints) audio = false;;
};
```